# generating random numbers between two numbers

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

Is it possible to generate random numbers that are almost equally spaced which shouldnot be exactly same as `numpy.linspace` output

I look into the `numpy.random.uniform` function but it doesnot give the required results.

Moreover the the summation of the values generated by the function should be same as the summation of the values generated by numpy.linspace function.

code

```
import random
import numpy as np
random.seed(42)
data=np.random.uniform(2,4,10)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this trick by combining `numpy.linspace` and `numpy.random.uniform` and `random choice two indexes and increase one of them and decrease other` help you:
(You can change `size=10`, `threshold=0.1` for how random numbers are bigger or smaller)

```
import numpy as np
size = 10
theroshold = 0.1
r = np.linspace(2,4,size) # r.sum()=30
# array([2.        , 2.22222222, 2.44444444, 2.66666667, 2.88888889,
#        3.11111111, 3.33333333, 3.55555556, 3.77777778, 4.        ])

c = np.random.uniform(0,theroshold,size)
# array([0.02246768, 0.08661081, 0.0932445 , 0.00360563, 0.06539992,
#        0.0107167 , 0.06490493, 0.0558159 , 0.00268924, 0.00070247])

s = np.random.choice(range(size), size+1)
# array([5, 5, 8, 3, 6, 4, 1, 8, 7, 1, 7])

for idx, (i,j) in enumerate(zip(s, s[1:])):
    r[i] += c[idx]
    r[j] -= c[idx]

print(r)
print(r.sum())
```

Output:

```
[2.         2.27442369 2.44444444 2.5770278  2.83420567 3.19772192
 3.39512762 3.50172642 3.77532244 4.        ]

30
```

Comment: as it requires np.linspace  to accomplish the task, can you please incorporate another tricks: the sum of the output of the function should be same as  the sum of the numbers generated by numpy.linspace

Comment: @snu, you need to mention this in your question. adding sample input and output in your question that you require.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider drawing random samples around the output of `numpy.linspace`. Setting these numbers as the mean of the normal distribution and setting the variance not too high would generate numbers close to the output of `numpy.linspace`. For example,

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> exact_numbers = np.linspace(2.0, 10.0, num=5)
>>> exact_numbers
array([ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10.])
>>> approximate_numbers = np.random.normal(exact_numbers, np.ones(5) * 0.1)
>>> approximate_numbers
array([2.12950013, 3.9804745 , 5.80670316, 8.07868932, 9.85288221])
```